# GOOGAPPUID is not between 0 and 999

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies

According to the documentation for traffic splitting a cookie will be set to control traffic splitting with a number between 0 and 999. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#traffic-splitting

This has been working fine for quite some time. But now whenever I clear my cookies and reload my solution, the GOOGAPPUID is no longer a number between 0 and 999.

Instead I am now getting a value like:

- xCgkQ3wMg28WhrgU
- xCgkQjAcg9sehrgU

This is a screenshot of my cookie information: http://screencast.com/t/z2fjR4xgYfB

I cannot find any information about a change in the traffic splitting, so I am bit puzzled why this happens. Does anybody know or have an idea why?

thanks,

Thomas

Comment: often the documents are updated later. If traffic splitting continues to work the specific implementation can be ignored, no?

Comment: I have this trouble, too. Have you had the answer? For now I can not force my own browser to a version by changing cookie's value.

Comment: Same issue.  Any idea how to manually set the cookie so a specific app version can be requested?

Comment: Same question here