# GOOGAPPUID cookie algorithm

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies

From Google's documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#traffic-splitting, GOOGAPPUID value should be in range 0-999.

For now, its value is is a string, such as: `xCgkQ3wMg28WhrgU`.

Now I want to change my cookie to use a specific version on my GAE app,

does anyone know how is the GOOGAPPUID generated?

**Update**

*Just found a trick*.

The cookie's value is not random, I guess that it is a type of hashing and the cookie value for each version is fixed.

So, by trying many times and save the cookie value for each version, I can force to access to a version by changing the cookie to the value that corresponding with the version.

For example, suppose that I have 2 versions A and B. After trying, I see that GOOGAPPUID is xAAAA for version A, and xBBBB for version B.

Now, if I want to access version A, just change GOOGAPPUID to xAAAA.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915256/googappuid-is-not-between-0-and-999

Comment: Related to https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12267

Comment: Yeah, I have read both above links when I searched for this problem. Since those links were created few months ago, so I recreate this question with hope that someone can help.

Comment: I have just found a trick, updated to the question.